# Rails/ActiveRecord: save changes to a model's associated collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Do I have to save modifications to individual items in a collection for a model, or is there a method I can call to save them when I save the model.

`#save` doesn't seem to do it.  For example:

```
irb> rental = #...
#=> #<Rental id: 18737, customer_id: 61, dvd_id: 3252, date_rented: "2008-12-16 05:00:00", date_shipped: "2008-12-16 05:00:00", date_returned: "2008-12-22 05:00:00">
irb> rental.dvd
#=> #<Dvd id: 3252, title: "The Women of Summer", year: 1986, copies: 20, is_new: false, is_discontinued: false, list_price: #<BigDecimal:1a48f0c,'0.1599E2',8(8)>, sale_price: #<BigDecimal:1a48ed0,'0.1599E2',8(8)>>
irb> rental.dvd.copies += 1
#=> 21
irb> rental.save
#=> true
irb> rental.dvd
#=> #<Dvd id: 3252, title: "The Women of Summer", year: 1986, copies: 21, is_new: false, is_discontinued: false, list_price: #<BigDecimal:1a2e9cc,'0.1599E2',8(8)>, sale_price: #<BigDecimal:1a2e97c,'0.1599E2',8(8)>>
irb> Dvd.find_by_title('The Women of Summer')
#=> #<Dvd id: 3252, title: "The Women of Summer", year: 1986, copies: 20, is_new: false, is_discontinued: false, list_price: #<BigDecimal:1a30164,'0.1599E2',8(8)>, sale_price: #<BigDecimal:1a30128,'0.1599E2',8(8)>>
```

In the above example, the copy of the DVD that the rental has doesn't seem to update the copy in the DB (note the differing number of copies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do a rental.dvd.save after you increment the value or in the above case you could use

```
rental.dvd.increment!(:copies)
```

which will also automatically save, note the '!' on increment!

Answer (score 22):

You can configure ActiveRecord to cascade-save changes to items in a collection for a model by adding the `:autosave => true` option when declaring the association. [Read more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).

Example:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cash_order, :autosave => true
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> You have to do this yourself

This isnt entirely true. You can use the "build" method which will force a save. For the sake of example assume that you have a Company model and Employees (Company has_many Employees). You could do something like:

```
acme = Company.new({:name => "Acme, Inc"})
acme.employees.build({:first_name => "John"})
acme.employees.build({:first_name => "Mary"})
acme.employees.build({:first_name => "Sue"})
acme.save
```

Would create all 4 records, the Company record and the 3 Employee records and the company_id would be pushed down to the Employee object appropriately.

Comment: You're referring to creating new models; the question and the answer you reference are referring to saving changes on existing models.

Comment: Important to note that this only works in the case of new model instances.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this yourself.  [Active Record does not cascade save operations in has_many relations after the initial save.](http://javathehutt.blogspot.com/2006/05/rails-realities-part-12-active-record.html)

You could automate the process with a `before_save` callback.

Comment: I like the idea of a before_save callback, but I'd worry about explosive recursion - another scenario I have here is customers and dvds each have many rentals, so I can do, say customer.rentals.first.dvd.rentals.first.customer, and cascading before_saves might get a bit out of hand, I worry.

Answer (score 1):

This post can be useful:
http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=267

Erik describe how to use "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the model and <% f.fields_for %> in the view to do the job.

Its detailed description can be found in:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html