# Is possible to recursively save a record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, `user` has one `list`, `list` has many `item`s, and I have the following code in the controller:

```
@user = User.new()
@list = List.new()
(1..10).each { |i| @list.items << (Item.new(:order => i)) }
@user.list = @list
```

Now if I call `@user.save`, `@list` and 10 `item`s wouldn't be save to the database. How should I rewrite this code?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @Magne yes, it possible to save models recursively. If you have any trouble check this out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html If there is still something wrong then post your models, associations and simple case. Original post has no information about models' relations.

Comment: After calling `@user.save`, are there any errors on the model? i.e. what's the value of `@user.errors` at that point?  what is the value of `@user.list.errors`?

Answer (score 10):

By setting up appropriate associations and validations you can ensure that when you save the user, the associated list and items are saved at the same time. Furthermore, you can ensure that everything is saved in a single transaction and that the save will be aborted if a child record cannot be saved.

Given the following model definitions for User, List and Item

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  validates_associated :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  validates_associated :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Calling `user.save` on a user with an invalid list item will now return false and none of the records will be saved.  You can query `user.errors` to find out why the save was aborted.

```
user = User.new
list = user.build_list
list.items.build(name: nil) 
user.save # => false
user.errors.messages # => {:list=>["is invalid"]}
user.list.error.messages # => {:items=>["is invalid"]}
```

Since Item validates presence of name, the item's save failed and none of the records were saved.  All you should see in your SQL log are something like:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Now if all records are valid:

```
user = User.new
list = user.build_list(name: 'My List')
list.items.build(name: 'Widget')
user.save # => true
```

ActiveRecord will save the records in the correct order in order to set foreign_keys. All 3 inserts are also wrapped in a transaction:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `lists` (`name`) VALUES ('My list')
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`list_id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'Widget')
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`list_id`) VALUES (4)
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: note that `validates_associated` doesn't work with `has_one`. for that you'd have to write `has_one :classname, validates: true`. Ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: @Magne, my solution does not utilize a `has_one` association.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was using.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `@user.list = @list`.

After that, calling `@user.save` should save everything.

Comment: But if @list can't pass the validations, how can I know it? `@user.save` still return `true` and `@user.save!` doesn't raise anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure ActiveRecord to cascade-save changes to items in a collection for a model by adding the :autosave => true option when declaring the association. [Read more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).

Example:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cash_order, :autosave => true
    ...
end
```

Credits to @skydump for this answer, in a similar question: [Rails/ActiveRecord: save changes to a model's associated collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869873/rails-activerecord-save-changes-to-a-models-associated-collections)

Answer (score 0):

If you have many lists in a user, you can use the has_many :lists in user model. Then lists table must have a user_id column.

In the controller you can get all lists of a user by using user.lists which will return the lists array of that user. You can add more list to user like user.lists << new_list.

I think this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Rails knows how to handle this. There is several ways depending on you design, and if I understand correctly you need to raise exception when a validation error occurs. Try this:

```
# Create a new User without saving it
@user = User.new(name: 'example')

# Create a new List, save it immediately
# and raise an exception if a validation failed
@user.create_list!(label: 'something')

# Similar to above, the Item will be saved in database immediately
# And exception will be raised for invalid records
(1..10).each {|i| @user.list.items.create!(order: i) } 

# Finaly save your user record, note that I am using save! with a bang
# To raise an exception for an invalid record
@user.save!
```

Side note: While doing this, you must wrap all thos operations in a transaction block, doing so will ensure database consistency. Example if one of your `list` is invalid and fails to save, the transaction block will rollback the records previously created in the database, leaving no garbage records.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @user = User.new(name: 'example')
  @user.create_list!(label: 'something')
  (1..10).each {|i| @user.list.items.create!(order: i) } 
  @user.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `accept_nested_attributes_for` so when a user gets save,so its associated records will autosave too.Please go through this ..... [accept_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [example of nested attributes from railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)