# ActiveRecord save all changes to has_many childs on parent save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to update a parent object (`Client`) and associated child objects (`License`). It is possible that either of these objects is new, that's why I have to check for existing objects to update and if there aren't any I have to create them.

My code currently looks like this:

```
return nil unless params.has_key?('client_uid')
client = Client.find_by_uid(params['client_uid'])
if client.nil?
  client = Client.new(uid: params['client_uid'])
end
client.app = params['application']
client.app_version = params['application_version']
...

licenses = params['licenses']
licenses.each do |licenseInfo|
  next unless licenseInfo.has_key?('application')
  license = client.licenses.find_by_application(licenseInfo['application'])
  if license.nil?
    license = License.new
    # add license without instantly saving
    client.association(:licenses).add_to_target(license)
    license.application = licenseInfo['application']
  end
  license.options = licenseInfo['options']
  ...
end
client.last_seen = Time.zone.now
client.save
```

This is able to create new clients and update existing ones from the values in the `params`, as well as adding new licenses for the client (I will implement deleting old licenses later). The problem is that changes to *existing licenses* aren't saved when I call `client.save`.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if ActiveRecord really isn't able to handle a situation like this. I already searched for this problem and tried to explicitly specify `autosave: true` for the `License` class' `belongs_to` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10308972/3326982), but this didn't have any effect.

In conclusion, my question is: What do I have to change to be able to save my `Client` together with all changes (new, changed, deleted) to his `licenses`?

EDIT:
I tried manually saving all licenses and putting this together in a transaction:

```
Client.transaction do
  client.save
  client.licenses.each do |license|
    license.save
  end
end
```

But this didn't work, either. Now I'm confused....

Comment: did you use accept_nested_attributes for License in Client model

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @praga2050 no, I didn't... I'll try that

Comment: @praga2050 oh well... that should have been obvious... \*facepalm\* would you make that an answer so I can accept this? Thanks for your help

Comment: done i have added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :licenses
```

in Client model. This would help you to save the child objects

as mentioned in comment. Please refer this link

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html